# How to auto-trigger onscroll when dynamically adding content with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, scroll, eventtrigger

With `.on(scroll` or `.scroll(` we can detect window or element scrolling when we do a physical scroll, by either dragging the scrollbar or using the mousewheel.

But it cannot be **auto-triggered** with dynamically added content.

Here is the an example: http://jsfiddle.net/vs5bR/

Is there any solution for this? I'v seen the DOM check method, which checks DOM element change all the time, and doesn't seem to be a good one.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to delegate the scroll event.

look at the documentation for `.on()` here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

In short.. if you hand a "selector" parameter to the `.on()` function your handler will be also be attached to any element added after your call to `.on()`.

This was previously done using [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) which is now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution, but it's for Firefox only

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/MozScrolledAreaChanged?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDetecting_document_width_and_height_changes#Example

```
document.addEventListener("MozScrolledAreaChanged", function( event ) {
    // do something
}, false);
```

I'm still waiting for a cross-browser solution...

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll the div automatically. This will trigger the scroll event as well.
Look at the javascript in [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vs5bR/5/)

Add the following to the click event. This sample is using the jQuery selector to get the element, but you could do that without jQuery as well

```
var mydiv = $('#content')[0];
mydiv.scrollTop = mydiv.scrollHeight;
```